# How can I add a python tuple to a YAML file using pyYAML?

Tags: python, pyyaml

The title is fairly self-explanatory.

When I save a tuple to a YAML file, I get something that looks like this:

```
ambient:  !!python/tuple [0.3, 0.3 ,0.3]
```

When I try to load it with `yaml.safe_load(file_object)`, I keep getting an error that reads:

```
yaml.constructor.ConstructorError:  could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/tuple'
```

What needs to be done?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In pyyaml, the SafeLoader does not include a loader for the python native types, only the types defined in the yaml spec.  You can see the types for the `SafeLoader` and the `Loader` here in the interaction sample below.

You can define a new Loader class that adds in the python tuple, but not other types, so it should still be pretty safe:

```
import yaml

class PrettySafeLoader(yaml.SafeLoader):
    def construct_python_tuple(self, node):
        return tuple(self.construct_sequence(node))

PrettySafeLoader.add_constructor(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/tuple',
    PrettySafeLoader.construct_python_tuple)

doc = yaml.dump(tuple("foo bar baaz".split()))
print repr(doc)
thing = yaml.load(doc, Loader=PrettySafeLoader)
print thing
```

resulting in:

```
'!!python/tuple [foo, bar, baaz]\n'
('foo', 'bar', 'baaz')
```

See below for the constructors associated with the SafeLoader and the Loader classes.

```
>>> yaml.SafeLoader.yaml_constructors
{None: <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_undefined>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:binary': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_binary>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:bool': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_bool>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:float': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_float>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_int>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_map>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_null>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:omap': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_omap>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:pairs': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_pairs>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:seq': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_seq>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:set': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_set>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_str>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:timestamp': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_timestamp>}

>>> yaml.Loader.yaml_constructors
{None: <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_undefined>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:binary': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_binary>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:bool': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_bool>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:float': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_float>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_int>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_map>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_null>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:omap': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_omap>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:pairs': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_pairs>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/bool': <unbound method Constructor.construct_yaml_bool>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/complex': <unbound method Constructor.construct_python_complex>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/dict': <unbound method Constructor.construct_yaml_map>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/float': <unbound method Constructor.construct_yaml_float>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/int': <unbound method Constructor.construct_yaml_int>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/list': <unbound method Constructor.construct_yaml_seq>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/long': <unbound method Constructor.construct_python_long>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/none': <unbound method Constructor.construct_yaml_null>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/str': <unbound method Constructor.construct_python_str>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/tuple': <unbound method Constructor.construct_python_tuple>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/unicode': <unbound method Constructor.construct_python_unicode>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:seq': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_seq>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:set': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_set>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_str>,
 u'tag:yaml.org,2002:timestamp': <unbound method SafeConstructor.construct_yaml_timestamp>}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

At least according to [the PyYAML documentation](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#LoadingYAML):

> The function yaml.safe_load limits this ability to simple Python objects like integers or lists.

The list, [as you can see in the source](http://pyyaml.org/browser/pyyaml/trunk/lib/yaml/constructor.py#L416), is somewhat more extensive but does not include `tag:yaml.org,2002:python/tuple`.

It appears that if you are generating a `!!python/tuple` type in your YAML file, you are using `dump()` as opposed to `safe_dump()`. If that's the case, you should probably switch to using `load()` in place of `safe_load()`, as files created by `dump()` are not guaranteed to be loadable by `safe_load()`. (See the [description of `safe_dump()`](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#Theyamlpackage)).

Comment: I added the missing word *not*, but I'm not sure whether you didn't actually want to formulate it the other way round...

Comment: Under what conditions would a reasonable person consider the use of yaml.loader (as opposed to safe_loader) dangerous?  I'm writing a game that loads assets defined in a YAML file.  A malicious download could presumably overwrite my YAML files, thereby having my game load dangerous code, but that seems to be an end-user issue.  There's not much I can do ... right?

Comment: @blz YAML can be used for configuration and communication between different projects. If your YAML is from a source you don’t control, you don’t want to use `yaml.load`.

Answer (score 3):

For those, who are looking for an up-to-date answer.

Currently, this issue can be solved by using `yaml.FullLoader`.

```
import yaml
yaml_file = open("path/to/filename.yaml", 'r')
loaded_yaml = yaml.load(yaml_file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
```

Then entries marked as tuples as below will be correctly parsed without any issues.

`!!python/tuple [0.3, 0.3 ,0.3]`

Comment: I know it's not safe, but... your solution is the most simple and straightforward.